# How can I add fonts to Libre Office Writer?

Tags: fonts, libreoffice-writer

New laptop, latest versions of software downloaded. Among the software I use a lot is Libre Office Writer. One of my documents has lost two of its fonts, namely Papyrus and Bookman Old Style.

They appear in the font box as italicized, indicating that's what they were set to, but not available. How can I get these fonts back/install them onto my computer and/or into Libre Office?

Comment: Which OS are you using?
On linux mint, if I add any font to the `.font`, it will be also avaiable on libreoffice-writer

Comment: Windows 10, [un]fortunately

Comment: Did the specific document to which you refer have these two fonts available to LO Writer before it "lost" them? Are they available to LO Writer if you create a new document? I use LO Writer on Win10 and it works with Bookman Old Style without a problem. I don't have Papyrus but AIUI it's free so all you have to do is download and install it. The more general answer to the question is that you don't have to add fonts to LO Writer specifically. All you have to do is install them to your OS and they will be available to LO Writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two probably came with Microsoft Office.

Bookman Old Style is one of the Postscript base-35 fonts, so free equivalents are widely available, such as *URW Bookman L* and *Bonum*. For Papyrus, you would probably need an MS Office install disc.

Comment: There is no need to involve MS Office. Papyrus is free and can be downloaded from [here](https://befonts.com/papyrus-font.html) for example.